# How can I show OrderId on log text as Log4j pattern layout

Tags: java, log4j, log4net-appender, graylog, threadcontext

I'm having trouble getting a log message to display the right way. I'm using this Log4J pattern layout:

```
pattern="ORDERID : $${ctx:ORDERID} %msg%n"
```

I want to see output like:

> ORDERID: 123 Test Context

But this is the output I am getting:

> ORDERID : ${ctx:ORDERID} Test Context

This is the code that's generating the log message:

```
@Test
public void testThreadContext() {
    ThreadContext.push("Message only");
    ThreadContext.push("int", 1);
    ThreadContext.push("int-long-string", 1, 2L, "3");
    ThreadContext.push("ORDERID", "123");
    logger.info("Test Context");
    ThreadContext.clearAll();
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `ThreadContext.push("ORDERID", "$123");`? I don't think there's a way to escape the $ sign. If you want more info: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html

Comment: If you don't mind having an space between you can use `pattern="ORDERID : $ ${ctx:ORDERID} %msg%n"`

Comment: @Eldelshell thanks. I handle it thank for give document url. I have used ThreadContext.put instead of ThreadContext.push. İt is  work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ThreadContext.put instead of ThreadContext.push. İt is work.

ThreadContext.put("ORDERID", "123"); instead of   ThreadContext.push("ORDERID", "123");

Result Log Text Url

[image]